# Disable Case Sensitivity in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database, and I connect to it via a rest webservice. However, I get an error saying:

> Could not find relation 'mytablename'

I believe this is because I have used camel casing in my database and the tables are named like `myTableName`. Is there anyway I can disable case sensitivity in postgresql? Or would I have to (if this is possible) make my rest calls case sensitive?

Comment: So you are using an ORM that uses quotes for all identifiers?

Comment: Used the `entity classes from database` option in netbeans.

Comment: Simple answer: **never** use double quotes for identifiers. Details are in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer started off as a comment but then evolved when I realized I might have an explanation for your problem.

All identifiers that are not double-quoted fall to lowercase in Postgres (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)).  So `SELECT * FROM MYTABLENAME` should behave identically to `SELECT * FROM mytablename`.

I think a likely cause of this is that Postgres is looking in the wrong schema for the `mytablename` table.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytablename
```

where `myschema` is the name of the schema containing the `mytablename` table.  If this doesn't fix the problem, you should make sure that the table actually exists.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Edited, thanks for your vigilence on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. fixed by renaming all tables to lowercase, since I am not sure how to find the schema name in postgresql.